# Needing row&col indices in code behind to get selected gridview cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using a gridview to click a cell. Once I click the cell I have a modal box open.

The modal has an Update and Cancel button.
I would like to get the clicked cell's selected row and column indices in the code behind to determine whether the clicked cell has a text value or not.

I'm able to do this in my code behind here:

```
protected void Grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    int selectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
}
```

This is what i have, which i need code for at the help comments:

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = //need help
    int selectedColumnIndex = // need help 

    if (Grd.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Text == " ")
    {
        //new, insert into db
    }

    else
    { 
        //update existing db record
    }
}
```

Comment: Snd the row and column values to the modal (hidden fields, query string, anyway you want) and then you'll have them when you click the update button. It doesn't make sense to go get values from two clicks prior.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewState` to pass the selected row index and the selected column index between postbacks. Add the following properties to your code behind

```
private int SelectedRowIndex
{
   get
   {
      if (ViewState["SelectedRowIndex"] == null)
      {
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         return (int)ViewState["SelectedRowIndex"];
      }
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["SelectedRowIndex"] = value;
   }
}

private int SelectedColumnIndex
{
   get
   {
      if (ViewState["SelectedColumnIndex"] == null)
      {
         return 0;
      }
      else
      {
         return (int)ViewState["SelectedColumnIndex"];
      }
   }
   set
   {
      ViewState["SelectedColumnIndex"] = value;
   }
}
```

then assign the selected row index and the selected column index to the properties above in `Grd_RowCommand`

```
protected void Grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    this.SelectedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    this.SelectedColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].ToString());
}
```

and get the values in `btnUpdate_Click`

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedRowIndex = this.SelectedRowIndex;
    int selectedColumnIndex = this.SelectedColumnIndex;

    if (Grd.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Text == " ")
    {
        //new, insert into db
    }

    else
    { 
        //update existing db record
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic, worked like a dream. Thank you so much. The only thing i changed was `if (Grd.Rows[selectedRowIndex].Cells[selectedColumnIndex].Text == "&nbsp;")
            {
                //insert into db
            }`